# How to swap more than 3 images when hover it?

Tags: javascript, image, hover

I have a image, when I hover it or mouseon it, I want the images change. Not only change once. Like I have the src of images: /images/start/1.jpg, /images/start/2.jpg, /images/start/3.jpg, /images/start/4.jpg, /images/start/5.jpg, /images/start/6.jpg, /images/start/7.jpg, /images/start/8.jpg, /images/start/9.jpg, /images/start/10.jpg.

```
<img src="/images/start/1.jpg" alt="Start" data-count="10" data-path="/images/start/{index}.jpg" />
```

In the .js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#images img" ).each(function() {
        var Ding = '';
        $('#images img').mouseover(function() {
            var url=''; var index = 2;
            var count = $(this).attr('data-count');
            var path = $(this).attr('data-path');
            var $this = $(this);
            Ding = setInterval(function() {
                if (index <= count) {
                    url = path.replace('{index}', index);
                    $this.attr('src', url).fadeIn();
                    index++;
                }
                else {
                    index = 1;
                    url = path.replace('{index}', index);
                    $this.attr('src', url).fadeIn();
                    index++;
                }
            }, 800);
            }),
            $('#images img').mouseout(function(){
                var path = $(this).attr('data-path');
                var $this = $(this);
                url = path.replace('{index}', 1);
                $this.attr('src', url).fadeIn();
                clearInterval(Ding);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: are you want to show new image every time user hovers it

Comment: If you already know how to change the first image, then just add a window.setTimeout to call the same function every N seconds.

Comment: show the code you have for the one image.

Comment: also are you using jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working.

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zqxo0rL9/)**

I've did it with jquery, but i think you know what that is. If you don't have Jquery in your site, paste this (in the `<head>` section):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = ['/images/start/1.jpg','/images/start/2.jpg','/images/start/3.jpg','/images/start/4.jpg','/images/start/5.jpg','/images/start/6.jpg','/images/start/7.jpg','/images/start/8.jpg','/images/start/9.jpg','/images/start/10.jpg',];
    var Ding = '';
    $('.imageChanger').hover(function(){
        var Counter = 0;
        Ding = setInterval(function(){
            if(Counter < (images.length - 1)){
                Counter++;
                $('img').attr('src',images[Counter]).fadeIn();
            }
            else{
                Counter = 0;
                $('img').attr('src',images[Counter]).fadeIn();
            }
        }, 3000);
    },function(){
        clearInterval(Ding);
    });
});
</script>
```

The first image, where the hover effect should take place, has got to have a `class='imageChanger'`. Try it out.

Comment: the OP has not tagged the question with [tag:jquery]

Comment: I have already tried your way, but it does't work;I don't know what is the problem; Can you help me to check?

Comment: I have already put the <script> in my header.php. When I hover it, there is nothing to change

Comment: @Dennis, Yes, it works. But What is my problem? In my case, I can't use this, it changes all my image in the whole page

Comment: @Dennis, I tried each line, I think Probably because of each(function(), when I come to $(this).attr('src', url); it doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Dennis, The problem is I have 16 images should be hovered on each image, so It's not a good idea to do this way.

Comment: It works now, I add a new line: $this=$(this);var count=$(this).attr('data-count'); var path=$(this).attr('data-path'); And then I replace these variables inside the setInterval(function{})   I have already changed in the code.   Thanks you so much.

Comment: @WeiweiHan no problem, you can accept my answer and maybe vote up if you liked it/helped you.